# XCODE not letting me test app on personal phone (Provisional License Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, licensing

So I do not have a paid developers account with apple, but I heard that you could test your xcode app on your phone without one. So, I followed the steps online, logged in to my apple ID, and for some reason when I plug in my iPhone and try to run the xcode file on my phone, I get this error message

> No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles."

Then when I click "fix issue", I get

> You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support"

Can someone please help? By the way, I have upgraded to the last Mac OS, and the latest version of xcode (7.3). I was able to compile it before, but after updating, I can't

Comment: I am afraid you can not do this without a paid developers account.

Comment: Wait really? I thought they updated xcode 7 so that this feature was available to people without a paid account too?

Comment: I remember that I was able to do it before

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't have membership:**

Clear your Code Signing Identities under the *Code Signing* category in your *Build Settings*:

[image: Provisioning]

**If you do have a membership:**

You need to create a new app id in iTunes Connect, with this app ID you create new provisioning profiles in Developer Portal for development and production environments which you need to download and install with Xcode. Then select the correct provisioning profile in your Build Settings

Comment: When you mean clear, you mean make it so my options in that tab are set to the same ones as yours in the picture? My apologies, I'm new to xcode! :) I did that, but the error still persists :(

Comment: Yes same as above. Cmnd + Shift + K to clean, then Cmnd + B to build and see?

Comment: Ahh mate then I can't help, sorry! :( Maybe try Apple Support if no answer after 7days?